Use of Comma in Email Sign-offs
I have seen commas in email signatures like this:
Best Regards,
[name]
Position,
Organization
and like this:
Best Regards,
[name]
Position
Organization
Which of these is correct. Is only comma after Best Regards sufficient or do we need commas for ending each line. Also why do we use commas in the first place? Can someone shed some light for me.

This question already addresses the comma after Best regards etc, and you can see this question about a comma after "Dear Mr X,". Questions about commas in street names are typically judged opinion-based, and in organisational routing it's probably the same.

The comma after best regards separates two distinct thoughts:

What the writer wishes—or in this case, what the writer feels—for the recipient and
Who the writer is.

The comma between the position and the organization is implicitly equivalent to a preposition like of, at, or in. It is certainly not necessary, but its use is not a flagrant violation either.

In formal letters, the first is never used. It just isn't. Why not say it?
